# What is difference between skimage.io.imread and matplotlib.pyplot.imread

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn

This is the code of image read using skimage :

```
from skimage.io import imread  
img1 = imread('path')
```

And this is the code of image read using matplotlib :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
img2 = plt.imread('path')
```

Comment: `imread` requires specifying `plugin`, which can be `matplotlib`, `pil`, etc. `plt.imread` seems to use `PIL`. Read the docs: [`matplotlib.image.imread`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/image.html#imread) & [`skimage.io.imread`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/main/skimage/io/_io.py#L16-L68).

Comment: I think, plt.imread do normalization automatically. Is am I correct?